# I'm using prestashop 1.7.5.2 Some customers want to remove the payment option from their store they want to use only the cart functionality

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I'm using prestashop 1.7.5.2. Some customers want to remove the payment option from their store. They want to use only the cart functionality.

```
-Add products.
-Add Address.
-Select courier.
```

I have tried removing the payment label using JS but this (order with an obligation to pay) doesn't let me place the order without selecting any payment option. I have searched in the admin panel but there is not any option to enable / disable that function.

Answer (score 0):

For do that you need to override Prestashop process checkout. For validate an order without payement